# How to test application for SharePoint 2019?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-2019

I am currently working on building an application for someone who wants it to run in their SharePoint 2019 environment. However they will not let me access their platform. Hence it's difficult to test.

I've setup a SharePoint Online tenant onwhich I can test it, but SPFx differs for these two versions (SharePoint 2019 uses v1.4.1 or lower, while Online uses the most recent version).

Is there any way I can test my SharePoint application for SPFx v1.4.1 (or lower) easily? It's a single page application built with React.

Comment: From experience I would say that the best option is writing an integration test against the exact version you are interested in. You can try installing the on-prem trial version https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57462

Comment: @Sasha thank you, I'm not very familiar with sharepoint itself. I can install this on my own PC? I just need the application to work on the SPFx version.

Comment: You would need to have a Windows Server for that. You can Install it "locally" on a virtual machine. Alternatively you can try the approach described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-support

Comment: @Sasha I'm installing it right now on a Windows Server 2019 VPS I bought a while ago. I hope I can get this to work ;)